# Why did Vaidya raj Sushen heal Lakshmana but never heal Surpanakha (who had her nose and ears cut off), in Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana

Vibhishana informed Sri Rama about a physician, Sushena, who lived in Lanka. Hanumana was asked to bring him. He brought Vaidya Sushena, together with his house. Vaidya Sushena, well aware that he was a physician attached to the kingdom of Ravana, and that treating Lakshmana could end up annoying Ravana, took a conscious ethical decision of treating the wounded Lakshmana.

Comment: Do u mean no body gave a treatment to Shurpanakha and she died due to those wounds?? Or u mean why she didn't go through plastic surgery?? The primary treatment might have been given by someone else as she used to live with Khara and not with Ravana after Ravana killed her husband...

Comment: Is their proof that Ravan killed her husband? Also their is nothing i found in Ramayan that suggests she died or got proper treatment.

Comment: "nothing i found in Ramayan that suggests she died or got proper treatment"- but you have claimed in your question "never heal Surpanakha" so your question is not backed up with sources...you are not sure whether someone gave treatment or not..then why you are claiming "never heal Surpanakha"...?

Comment: **"Is their proof that Ravan killed her husband?"** :-> Surpanakha: My husband should have been saved by thee in the battle. But he was slain by thy ownself in the battle ;art thou not ashamed of this ?"Being thus addressed by his bewailing sister, Ravana, consoling her in sweet words, said "sister, thy husband was slain by me in the conflict;.." Ravana also suggested her to stay in Dandaka forest with their cousin Khara.. - Uttar Kanda

Comment: Is their proof that Surpanakha was healed and got her nose/ears back?

Comment: You should tag it with Ramcharitmanas instead of Ramayana. Because Sushena is not a resident of Lanka according to Ramayana. He was a Vanara and helped the army even before that. In Ramcharitmanas, Hanuman brings sushena along with home.  In Ramayana, he doesn't. Also it was Jambavan who informed. Not Vibhishana about Sushena.